# Exercise 2.17 in Rudolf Lidl's Finite Fields big red book.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Ex. 2.17 on page 79 asks the following:

prove that:
$$f(t^q)=(f(t))^q \ \ \ \forall f(t)\in \mathbb{F}_q[t]$$
my attempt at solution:
Ok then I write a polynomial: $f(t)=a_0+a_1t+\ldots+a_mt^m$
and $f(t^q)=a_0+a_1t^q+\ldots + a_m t^{qm}$ and $(f(t))^q=(a_0+a_1t+\ldots +a_mt^m)^q$.

Now, how to finish this proof?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Over a field of characteristic $p$ where $p$ is prime, consider how $(x+y)^p$ simplifies using the binomial theorem.

Comment: But I have here sort of a generalized binomial theorem, don't I?

Comment: I mean multinomial.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist True, which immediately follows from the binomial one by induction.

Comment: @xbh I am telling you it's trivial stuff this abstract algebra.. :-)